# Start of match \zs seems to break my pattern

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, delimiter-matching

I am playing around with vim syntax, matching expressions like `name.subname` regardless of their layout. Here is a match pattern I came upon which does exactly what I want:

[image]

Now, I wish that `subname` would be the only colored part of my matches. This is a job for `\zs`, right? Here is the result:

[image]

Why is this so? Why does `\zs` break my pattern? How can I get all `subnames` in the first section colored and not the ones in the second section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here is my explanation: there are restrictions on multi-line patterns for syntax highlighting: `\zs` cannot be used if it makes it jump to a line which is not where the pattern started:

```
:helph syn-multi-line
```

And here is a neat workaround with the keyword `contains`

```
highlight link SubGroup Error
syntax match SubGroup '\<subname\>' contained
syntax match Constant '\<name\>[ \n]*\.[ \n]*\<subname\>' contains=SubGroup
```

[image]

Also, here is another, maybe more efficient one: only highlight the end of the pattern:

```
syntax match Error "\<name\>[ \n]*\.[ \n]*\<subname\>"he=-6
```

it seems to randomly color or not the intermediate `.` though.